# Get SharePoint user by email address

Tags: lookup-column, email, user

Is it possible to get the SharePoint user by email address?

I'm writing a SharePoint 2013 workflow and the steps are :

1. call a web service to get user email address
2. look up SharePoint user using email address
3. assign a task to the SharePoint user

I'm able to do step 1 and 3 but not sure how to do step 2 using SharePoint Designer and SharePoint Workflow 2013.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I was able to assign a task by following the steps as mentioned in the below image. 
Set the variable in step-1 to the email address you got from the web service.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Sure you can, SharePoint Provide the next method using C#

```
SPWeb.SiteUsers.GetByEmail("jhon@contoso.com")
```

This will return you a SPUser object, so your code should be like

```
SPUser oUser = SPWeb.SiteUsers.GetByEmail("jhon@contoso.com");
```

:) I Hope it helps you

Comment: Is there a way to enter this code in SharePoint 2013

Comment: The OP was asking how to do this with SharePoint Designer, C# code is not going to help much there unless they can write and deploy custom actions.